# Perl Regular Expression not replacing despite appearing to work on online tester

Tags: regex, perl

I've constructed the following regex:

```
(public\s\$log_path\s=\s'\/var\/www\/)(.*?)(?=\/)(.*)
```

I'm wanting to match the `public $log_path` line in the config file below and replace it using the following pattern:

```
$1test/$2$3
```

Which should give me:

`public $log_path = '/var/www/test/administrator/logs';`

My Perl one-liner is:
`perl -pe "s/(public\s\$log_path\s=\s'\/var\/www\/)(.*?)(?=\/)(.*)/$1test$2$3/" <file-name>.php`

But this doesn't seem to change anything and just prints the file back to the console.

The file contents are below:

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $MetaDesc = '';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $MetaTitle = '1';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $access = '1';
    public $cache_handler = 'file';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $caching = '0';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
    public $log_path = '/var/www/website/administrator/logs';
}
```

Any pointers for where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs and their expected outputs as well?

Comment: Strings in double quotes are expanded in the shell. It will remove all the unbackslashed backslashes. Use single quotes or double the backslashes.

Comment: What purpose serves this stand-alone single quote, in ...\s=\s'\/var...?

Comment: Can you spell out the line you'd like to have instead of the matched one?  (I am not sure whether those capture groups are right in what you give so an explicit expected output would help.)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes and define the single quote between double quotes:

```perl
perl -pe 's/(public\s\$log_path\s=\s'"'"'\/var\/www\/)(.*?)(?=\/)(.*)/$1test$2$3/' <file-name>.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely getting hung up in the shell quoting, which can be nasty on the best of days. This works under Bash:

```
perl -pe 's{^(\s*public\s+\$log_path\s+=\s+./var/www)/}{$1/test/};' test.php
```

It simplifies the escaping of the front-slashes by using alternate delimiters in the Perl substitution, and I cheat on the matching of the single-quote by matching anything in that position.

```
</tmp> $ cat test.php
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $MetaDesc = '';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $MetaTitle = '1';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $access = '1';
    public $cache_handler = 'file';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $caching = '0';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
    public $log_path = '/var/www/website/administrator/logs';
}

</tmp> $ perl -pe 's{^(\s*public\s+\$log_path\s+=\s+./var/www)/}{$1/test/};' test.php
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $MetaDesc = '';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $MetaTitle = '1';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $access = '1';
    public $cache_handler = 'file';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $caching = '0';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
    public $log_path = '/var/www/test/website/administrator/logs';
}
```

If you really *must* match the single quote at that position, you can do as @Ryszard Czech suggests and put them in double-quotes:

```
perl -pe 's{^(\s*public\s+\$log_path\s+=\s+'"'"'/var/www)/}{$1/test/};' test.php
```

For something like this, I find it best to get it working inside of a shell script first, then trying to convert it into a one-liner; you're not fighting the regex and the shell quoting both at the same time that way.